# Teamcity Launch Test on build result

Tags: teamcity

I have two build steps

[image]

in second step I am launching some UI Test that looks like:

```
DesiredCapabilities appCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
appCapabilities.SetCapability("app", @"ViewBrowser/bin/Debug/ViewBrowser.exe");
appCapabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "WPF");
var includeController = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(@"http://127.0.0.1:4723"), appCapabilities);
includeController.Manage().Window.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 20);
includeController.CloseApp();
```

But in my code I need to specify @"ViewBrowser/bin/Debug/ViewBrowser.exe". In my case what i need to place there because Test cannot find .exe file. I am new in Teamcity. Can you advice something?

Comment: just add in the test resourced or create directory in base and add ViewBrowser.exe there

Comment: @SeniorPomidor,How to do that? I need to set up artifacts?

Answer (score 0):

You can store ViewBrowser.exe in the resource folder or in the folder around your project.

and just take the file path. E.g.

```
string RunningPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory 
                    + "path/to/folder/ViewBrowser.exe";
```

or take from resources

```
string FileName = string.Format("{0}Resources\\ViewBrowser.exe", Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(RunningPath, @"path/to/folder")));
```